# Why does Docker Desktop show "Newer image available"?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-desktop

I am building a Docker image with the following base image in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.12-slim-bookworm
```

My build command is `docker build . --no-cache=true`.
The build logs are:

```
[+] Building 78.3s (17/17) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                  docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 741B                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.12-slim-bookworm                                                                                                                         1.8s
 => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 1.80kB                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [ 1/10] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.12-slim-bookworm@sha256:eb53cb99a609b86da6e239b16e1f2aed5e10cfbc538671fc4631093a00f133f2 
...
```

After the image is built, Docker Desktop shows that it is built with the base image `FROM python:3-slim`, and that `python:3-slim` has a newer image available, as shown in my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnEwq.png).

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74141798/23361424, since the build command includes `--no-cache=true`, it should pull the newest available image.

However, the sha256 digest from the build logs `eb53cb99a609b86da6e239b16e1f2aed5e10cfbc538671fc4631093a00f133f2` and the digest from the latest (as of today) python:3-slim image https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/python/3-slim/images/sha256-4e7d6f2672bd4a834eac99973679c7e73fbcd475d439b7569512bf478ed39c78?context=explore are different.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59463729/dockerhub-sha-digest-doesnt-match#61922050

Comment: Do you mean `docker build . --pull`?  I'd expect `--no-cache` to ignore the layer cache used to skip `RUN` lines, but not necessarily to pull the base image again.  Also note that an image doesn't actually contain the name of its base image, so Docker Desktop is guessing a little bit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with this build command: `docker build . --no-cache`.

The official documentation for `docker build` and its options is here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/#options

Apparently `docker build . --no-cache=true` uses the cache.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).